# Bottle upload xlsx and process with xls2db

Tags: python, bottle

I am looking to grab a xlsx file from a bottle upload and send the file to the xls2db module to populate a sqlite db but I don't seem to be passing the file properly.
#

```
     @route('/',method="GET")   # Select the xls sheet from this route
def testRoute():
    return ('''</br>
           <h1> Select the spreadsheet</h1>
           <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <input type="file" name="data" />

            <input type="submit"/>
       </form>  ''')


@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    name = request.forms.name
    data = request.files.data
    if name and data and data.file:
        raw = data.file.read() # This is dangerous for big files
        filename = data.filename
        #return "Hello %s! You uploaded %s (%d bytes)." % (name,   filename, len(raw))
        upload_xls(raw, filename)
```

## connect to database drop the tables if they exist and convert xls sheet to sqlite database

```
def upload_xls(raw, filename):
    conn = sqlite.connect("test_db.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    f = filename
    data = raw
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Requests;")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Complaints;")
    xls2db(data , "test_db.db")
    redirect("/work")
```

UPDATE - I am now getting this error.

```
    2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
    2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
    2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    return route.call(**args)
    2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
   2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
   2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/home/mcsl/mysite/bottle_app.py", line 91, in do_upload
   2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    upload_xls(file_path)
   2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/home/mcsl/mysite/bottle_app.py", line 22, in upload_xls
   2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    xls2db(file_name, "test_db.db")
   2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/home/mcsl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xls2db/__init__.py", line 29, in xls2db
  2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(infile)
  2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 435, in open_workbook
  2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 87, in open_workbook_xls
  2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 594, in biff2_8_load
  2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:    raise XLRDError("File size is 0 bytes")
 2016-02-16 22:16:55 ERROR:root:XLRDError: File size is 0 bytes
```

I can upload the file and I can now see it on the server but when I pass it to the function it is reporting that its empty.

```
    @route('/upload', method='POST')
    def do_upload():
        data = request.files.upload
        upload = request.files.get('upload')
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(data.filename)
        #check the file is an excel file
        if ext not in ( '.xls', '.xlsx'):
            return "File extension not allowed."

            save_path = "/home/mcslo/mysite".encode("utf-8")
            file_path= "{path}/{file}".format(path=save_path,        file=data.filename)
            raw = data.file.read() # This is dangerous for big file

           open_file = open(file_path, 'w')
           open_file.write(raw)
           open_file.close
           upload_xls(file_path)


    def upload_xls(file_name):
file_name = file_name
conn = sqlite.connect("test_db.sqlite")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Requests;")
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Complaints;")
xls2db(file_name, "test_db.db")
redirect("/work")
```

Comment: Per https://github.com/jfhbrook/xls2db/blob/master/xls2db/__init__.py#L23 you need to pass a filename or a workbook to `xls2b`.

Comment: Ah that's because it's not saved to disk... Let me think more about this

Comment: Can you try: `import openpyxl; wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(data.filename)` and then pass `wb` to your call to `upload_xls(raw, wb)` and then do: `xls2db(filename, "test_db.db")`

Comment: openpyxl.load_workbook(data.filename)
2016-02-12 14:34:52 ERROR:root:  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 119, in load_workbook
2016-02-12 14:34:52 ERROR:root:    raise InvalidFileException(unicode(e))
2016-02-12 14:34:52 ERROR:root:InvalidFileException: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Testthis.xlsx.xlsx'.           This is what I get .

Comment: I have decide to upload the file and save to disk then send it but it is saving as an empty file?

Comment: Maybe show the code for how you're writing the file.

Comment: `open_file.write(raw)`

Comment: Otherwise you've already read the file and there's nothing left to read at that point.

Comment: I have updated original question.